# Java: testing positive and negative values

Tags: java, logic

I need to test whether a late goal in a Soccer game has changed the result.

The project is centered around one Team, and it is regarding their results against various opponents. It is an investigation regarding the importance of late goals to a winning team.

In my Goals database I have a list of the times that goals were scored and whether or not they were scored by the Team or the Opposition.

There is a `Game` `Object` that stores things like `teamScore`, `oppScore`, a `result` (`String` that contains either W or L or D) etc.

The `Season` `Object` is used to collect and return the results.

When a goal is scored by the team it increments the `minutes` `Int[]` in the `Game`  at the correct minute:
`minute[GoalTime]++`

When a goal is scored by the team it decrements the `minutes` database at the correct minute:
`minute[GoalTime]++`

Therefore to find the score at any minute, we add up all the minutes that have been before:

```
int score85=0;

for (int g = 0; g <= 85; g++) {
score85+=minutes[g];
}
```

If I have `score90` and `score85` how do I compare them so that it only returns results where a late goal has changed the result? I wish to avoid logging games where a winning team has scored again post 85, as this makes no difference to the result. I’m only interested in goals that have had a direct impact on the outcome.

Here is what I have:

```
int difference = score90-score85;

if (difference>0 && score85<=0)
{
    if (result.equals("W") || result.equals("D"))
    {
    season.gamesWDByLateGoal++;
    }
}


  if (difference<0 && score85>=0)
  {
    if (result.equals("D") || result.equals("L")){
    season.gamesLDByLateGoal++;
    println(gameNumber);
    }
  }
```

How can I be sure that I am getting the right result? I am testing 1500+ games and I have been getting different answers.

Comment: what is your question if any? If you're looking for code review please go to the codereview.stackexchange site

Comment: This sounds like such an overcomplicated solution/problem solving task.

Comment: "How can I be sure my code works?" By writing tests...

Comment: How do those answers differ? What do you expect?

Comment: @null I don’t know what to expect. I have a fact checker doing it manually and he is getting different results. To me it seems there must be a simple logical way to test, but I just can’t think what it could be.

Comment: I would scan each game's data backwards - You do know the result of the match, so find the latest goal, take it off the team's result and check if the result has changed. You also have to define what is "Late Goal" - (last 5 mins? last 10?) and stop the search when you each the limit.

Answer (score 0):

The goal count is not a good solution:

```
minute[GoalTime]++
```

That means to have an array of 90 integers (the length of a usual soccer game is 90 minutes). You are doing statistics on data, so you should be familiar with some of the average values. I hope you agree that having 9 goals in a game is a lot. That means that 90% of those integers you have are useless most of the time.

Not only is it a waste of memory, but also a waste of time, as you have to step through all those integers (in the for loop) to find the game result.

In addition to that, not every game lasts 90 minutes.

- Since soccer players are paid like Hollywood actresses, they act as
  such and allowances of a few minutes are added to every period in
  order to compensate for their stage time.
- There can be an [overtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtime_%28sports%29#Knock-out_contests_.28including_professional_competition.29) of 2 additional 15 minute periods
- there were rules that could shorten the overtime, [see golden and silver goal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_goal).

Considering that, the idea of using the time as an index doesn't look that good.

On top of that, there can be a [penalty shoot-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_shoot-out_%28association_football%29), which causes goals that do not even have a time associated to them.

[Further down in the article, there's this demonstration how different rating systems handle penalty goals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_shoot-out_%28association_football%29#Win_or_draw.3F)

> In the calculation of UEFA coefficients, shoot-outs are ignored for club coefficients,[53] but not national team coefficients, where the shoot-out winner gets 20,000 points: more than the shoot-out loser, who gets 10,000 (the same as for a draw) but less than the 30,000 points for winning a match outright.[56] In the FIFA World Rankings, the base value of a win is three points; a win on penalties is two; a draw and a loss on penalties are one; a loss is zero.[54] The more complicated ranking system FIFA used from 1999 to 2006 gave a shoot-out winner the same points as for a normal win and a shoot-out loser the same points as for a draw; goals in the match proper, but not the shoot-out, were factored into the calculation.[57]

I highly recommend looking at the different systems to see which one makes most sense to you. After all, you cannot compare to another system if you have a different definition of winning and losing a game.

To complicate things further, goals can have different "values". Goals that are scored away are more valuable than those at home.

If two matches between A and B are as follows

- @A's home: A:1 B:1
- @B's home: A:2 B:2

A wins on aggregate, even though both games are draws.

Did I mention indoor soccer yet? =)

### conclusion

- Use an official system as a reference. If your system comes to the
  conclusion that the game was a draw, while the official saying is
  that itS' a win, then your system is not comparable to any official
  results and has thus very little meaningfulness. Make sure your system matches the official results.
- Store the goals as their time in a dynamic list associated with the team.

Finally, in a separate list, store results with a time. Whenever a goal is scored that changes the result, add another result object with the new result to this list. You now know all the times when the result changed, without discretising the entire timeline. To get a result at an arbitrary point in time, get the result from that list with the next smaller time stamp.

Comment: Thanks @null for this comprehensive answer: I agree with everything, but my solution does not need to include everything you have mentioned. It is mostly only EPL. 
Is my code inefficient? Probably. But as the final outcome is static, the code only needs to work once. 
I like the Results List idea, I will tinker with that

Comment: @jackoverflow does it answer your question though?

Comment: my apologies, I pressed `ENTER` rather than `SHIFT+ENTER`